# gtk ComboBoxEntry.get_child() returns none

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a problem with the gtk ComboBoxEntry. My program crashes when I try to change the text in the combobox. I use this code:

```
   gui.combo_txt_script.get_child().set_text(fshort)
```

It crashes with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_text'
```

The results of the following prints:

```
   print "combo:",gui.combo_txt_script
   print "entry:",gui.combo_txt_script.get_child()
```

is

```
combo: <gtk.ComboBoxEntry object at ... >
entry: None
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that reproduces the bug? Normally creating a ComboBoxEntry automatically creates its child entry. Maybe some code is destroying your ComboBoxEntry, or removing its child entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The program I use has different user levels. Every tab and thus every widget is not visible for every user level. Somehow, it happened that the user level could change by itself, which made the combo non existent.

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATED*

The get and set current value of `Gtk.ComboBox` objects is related to *model* attribute of these objects and you can set and/or get items similar below code:

```
model = combo.get_model()
value = model[combo.get_activate()][0]
# first index refers to row of list
# second index refers to cell in the row. by default an combo/combo-entry have one cell
combo.set_activate(list(model).index(value))
```